# Function Save in excel vba is acting as SaveAs

Tags: excel, vba, save, save-as

I have a macro, and I am struggeling with saving. The macro:

- opens second workbook from SharePoint
- unprotects it
- unprotects a sheet in the original workbook
- copies line(s)
- pastes those line(s) in the second workbook
- protects the sheet in the second workbook
- saves the second workbook
- closes it
- protects the sheet in original workbook

I have this macro in 4 files, always 1 original file - 1 second file. Two files are without any problems, but the other 2 files, I can't save the second file. It says that there is already a file with this name, and asks if I want to rewrite it.
Why does it ask that, when I am using the function `.Save`?
Or, if this cannot be managed, how do I write in the macro that it should choose - yes, rewrite?

Thank you.

I tried to use the combined function `Close SaveChanges:=True`, but it didnt help.

Comment: Is the file already there? did you check your folder?

Comment: @Aldert yes, the File is on the sharepoint, and the macro has no problem by opening it, unprotect, copy data. But will not save. What do you mean by checking folder? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to set `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` right before saving and restore it `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` right after that?

Comment: As you mention, your file is on SharePoint. Is anyone using the files at the same time? I think you need to look at how to open/check out the file. The problem most likely is that SharePoint makes versions of your file and saves files in between. So when your file gets autosaved, your reference in your code might be "old" so it sees it as "not the same file" and goes to Save as...

Comment: @atmo Yes, I did, but it only doesnt show the alert, but still doesnt save it.

Comment: @aldert Nobody else is using the document in the moment :(. I have the same macro for 2 another files on sharepoint, and it works there - and then this file and one more, and it doesnt work. I use .Open and have the path there, and then .Save and .Close. Thank you.

Comment: @Atmo I found out now, that the problem probably starts already by opening the document - it opens as readonly without asking (meaning when I dont use the DisplayAlerts function). Nobody else has the document open. When I try to open it manually, it opens normally. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

The beggining of the code:

Sub a()
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open("https://ABC.xlsx")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Workbooks("ABC.xlsx").Worksheets("AAA").Unprotect Password:="bla"

Comment: ReadOnly:=False didnt work :(

Comment: I thought your issue was when you save a workbook, as it overwrites another? Can you edit your question to make what happens to what workbook extra clear?

Comment: I do not believe you should change your question, only edit the content. So we know now it is related to opening the worksheet in readonly so it is logic it does a saveas.

Comment: Can you add your code of opening?